# 70002 error when trying to register a secondary customer profile (ISV)

Tags: curl, twilio, registration, twilio-api

I'm attempting to complete step 1.7 here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/a2p-10dlc/onboarding-isv-api#17-assign-end-users-supporting-document-and-primary-customer-profile-to-the-empty-secondary-customer-profile-that-you-created

I am able to `add authorized_representative_1`, `customer_profile_business_information`, and `primary_customer_profile` successfully to the secondary customer profile, but when trying to add the address, I receive the following error:

> "body": "{"code": 70002, "message": "Attempting to add invalid Object Type to Bundle", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/70002", "status": 400}"

I have verified that the correct address sid is being passed (pulled the id from within my twilio account) and that the address looks properly formed within the twilio console.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are passing the supporting document
"sid": "RDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",

and not the actual address sid
"sid": "ADXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",